# desktop open file by JAX-WS

Tags: apache, tomcat, jax-ws, desktop

I use Tomcat 8.5 and JDK 8 for develop webservice openfile by「Desktop desktop Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)」.

When use eclipse run on server, open file success not problem. 
when make 「.war」file and upload into server, then run service, it run success but can't open file.

I try research, but not success, anybody help me.

Comment: I'd have a look at this, I'm guessing your server is linux based. [how to find which libraries does java desktop api require on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296555/how-to-find-which-libraries-does-java-desktop-api-require-on-linux)

Comment: Thank for advance, but i use windows 8.1 for webservice.

Comment: Your "server" is windows 8.1?  Either way, it looks like you have files on your build path in eclipse that dont end up in the war when deploying.  When you deploy locally through eclipse, write click the deployment that shows on the server and do show in file browser.  navigate to the lib folder, note the jars being shown.  Next deploy the war on the "server", navigate to the webapps folder, see what jars are now in the lib folder, if there aren't any, then you need to add them to the "deployment assembly".  I can give you a answer if thats the problem.

Comment: Thanks you. But my problem it can't call Desktop.getDesktop().open(path) from wsdl. You have any idea for this problem?

Comment: You're trying to open a wsdl file which works locally but not on the server?  Is the wsdl file for a web service reference in your code?